# Are there Web Applications that are using Open Source Lightning Web Components Framework?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I know LWC and now would like to develop my own web application. Is LWC a good choice? If yes, what stack should I be using?

Comment: Web Components is a standard-ish component model. There are many [WC frameworks](https://www.webcomponents.org/), LWC being one of them. LWC skews to Salesforce which may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any *professional* web apps (nor would they be immediately obvious), but people certainly have written LWC-based apps (including myself). The default stack for this is a simple NodeJS-based server, and it works well.

Simply run `npx create-lwc-app` and follow the prompts. From here, you can almost directly run this on Heroku, just add a Procfile and fix up the project.json file to include any extra dependencies you need (`npm-run-all` if you want to run the API server and static server at once, which is a default script).

If you don't want to go this route, well, you can use pretty much whatever you want. LWC is all client-side, so as long as you can place the files in correct directories and serve static files, you have everything you need. You could use nginx, NodeJS express server, whatever Microsoft is calling a server these days, Apache, etc. Use whatever you feel comfortable using, LWC is perfectly portable across all platforms.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox and @pchittum!

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of professional web apps, both the LWC component reference, and the LWC [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) (which is soon to be retired) make use of LWC. Given its legacy, I don't think the component reference is necessarily a from-the-ground-up LWC app. But the playground itself is. I believe it was one of the early initial proving grounds for LWC.

These probably aren't as satisfying as perhaps if there were a bunch of examples of LWC apps in the wild (not built and run by Salesforce). But it felt worth mentioning these.